# Какой код работает быстрее?

Tags: ассемблер

Заодно кому не сложно, объяните, что делают эти инструкции.

Код №1

```
mov eax,[$00417e88]
mov byte ptr [eax+$0c],$ff
```

Код №2

```
add dword ptr [$00417e90],$02
mov eax,[$00417e90]
mov byte ptr [eax],$ff
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Код №1**

```
mov eax,[$00417e88]
mov byte ptr [eax+$0c],$ff
```

1. читает в eax двойное слово(четыре байта) из адреса 00417e88
2. пишет в eax+0c байт FF.

**Код №2**

```
add dword ptr [$00417e90],$02
mov eax,[$00417e90]
mov byte ptr [eax],$ff
```

1. прибавляет 02 к значению, находящемуся по адресу 00417e90
2. читает это значение в eax
3. используя его в качестве указателя пишет в него байт FF

Из вышесказанного очевидно, что код №1 работает чуть быстрее, т.к. в нем на одну инструкцию меньше. Кроме того, второй код модифицирует данные в памяти только для того, что-бы использовать их в качестве указателя, что мне кажется некорректным -  надо смотреть по обстоятельствам.

Comment: Если что, это коды генерируемые компилятором Delphi XE: 

Первый код: 

bb^[3].rgbBlue:=$ff;

А второй:

inc(buf,2);
buf^:=$ff;

Comment: Ну да, первый вариант мне определенно нравится больше. И дело тут даже не в скорости - современные процессоры выполняют миллиарды операций в секунду - одна лишняя ничего не изменит. Первый код более понятен и логичен.

Comment: Просто дело в том, что эту операцию надо выполнять сос корость 400млн. раз в секунду)))

Comment: Тем более, операции с памятью гораздо медленнее операций с регистрами. Регистры находятся непосредственно в процессоре, в то время как память где-то "далеко". По сути второй код работает с памятью трижды - две операции записи, одно чтение. В первом случае одно чтение и одна запись.

Comment: @ололо, если 0xff надо писать в большое количество байт подряд, то лучше писать сразу двойными словами (думаю можно сформировать FFFFFFFF в регистре и заносить его в память) и делать цикл увеличивая должным образом регистр базы (в Вашем случае eax) и не перезагружать его из памяти каждый раз. Ну и т.д.

@dword, память памяти рознь. Та куда пишут 400млн. раз это наверняка RAM. А остальная наверняка кэш процессора.

Comment: Тут перезаписывается одно поле структуры. Если структура 4байтовая, то лучше работать с ней целиком как с двойным словом, а не с каждым ее полем в отдельности.